# Speeding up my code for a volume of a sphere (Nested while loops)

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to speed up my code for calculating the volume of a sphere (see code below).
This volume of the sphere is produced by calculating small volume segments, dv, and summing them into a volume, vol.

In reality this code is just a sanity check before I apply the calculations to other sphere like objects which will have symmetrical properties, hence I should be able to increase the speed of the code by calculating over a small volume and multiplying the end result.

Replace 360 and 180 in while (phid<=(360.0/adstep)) and while (thetad<=(180.0/adstep)) with 180 and 90 respectively and you quarter the calculations required meaning that you can simply multiply the final vol by 4.0.

This works if I set phi to and leave theta at 180, halving the calculations.
But it doesn't like it when I set theta to 90.

Ouput:

```
Phi 360, Theta 180
Actual Volume       Calculated Volume   % Difference
4.18879020478639053 4.18878971565348923 0.00001167718922403

Phi 180, Theta 180
4.18879020478639053 4.18878971565618219 0.00001167712493440

Phi 180, Theta 90
4.18879020478639053 4.18586538829648180 0.06987363946500515
```

You can see in the above that the first two calculations are near identical (I assume the difference is due to precision errors) while the last one gives significantly different results. Could the nested loops cause issues?

Any help would be appreciated as I haven't found anything in my research (google & stack overflow) to describe the problem I'm having.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double thetar, phir, maxr, vol, dv, vol2, arstep, adstep, rad, rad3, thetad, phid, ntheta, nphi;
cout << fixed << setprecision(17); // Set output precision to defined number of decimal places. Note Double has up to 15 decimal place accuracy

vol=0.0;            // Initialise volume and set at zero
adstep=0.1;     // Steps to rotate angles in degrees
arstep=(adstep/180.0)*M_PI;     // Angle steps in radians
phid=1.0;           // Phi in degrees starting at adstep
maxr = 1.0;         // Radius of the sphere

// Loop to calculate volume

while (phid<=(360.0/adstep))            // Loop over Phi divided by adstep. This scales the loop to the desired number of calculations.
{
    phir=((phid*adstep)/180.0)*M_PI;        // Phi in radians
    thetad=1.0;                             // Theta in degrees, reset to initial adstep value
    while (thetad<=(180.0/adstep))          // Loop over Theta divided by adstep. Like Phi loop, this scales the loop to the desired number of calculations
    {
        thetar=((thetad*adstep)/180.0)*M_PI;    // Convert theta degrees to radians
        dv = ((maxr*maxr*maxr) * sin(thetar) * arstep * arstep) / 3.0;      // Volume of current segment
        vol += dv;      // Summing all the dv value together to generate a global volume
        thetad+=1.0;    // Increase theta (degrees) by a single step
    }
    phid+=1.0;      // Increase phi (degrees) by a single step
}

vol = vol*1.0; // Volume compensated for any reduction in phi and theta

rad3 = (3.0*vol)/(4.0*M_PI);    // volume equivalent radius^3
rad = pow(rad3,(1.0/3.0));      // volume equivalent radius
vol2 = (4.0/3.0)*M_PI*(maxr*maxr*maxr);     // Calculated volume of a sphere given initial maxr

// Diagnostic output
cout << vol2 << " " << vol << " " << ((vol2-vol)/vol)*100.0 << endl;

}
```

Edit: Corrected starting values of phid and thetad to 1.0

Edit 2:
I just wanted to update, for future viewers, that using the Kahan summation algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) has virtually negated all my precision errors due to the summation of a small number onto a large number. There are other methods out there but this is one of the simplest and does the job I need it to.
For posterity this is the example psuedocode taken from the wikipedia page on the topic:

```
function KahanSum(input)
 var sum = 0.0
 var c = 0.0                  // A running compensation for lost low-order bits.
 for i = 1 to input.length do
    var y = input[i] - c     // So far, so good: c is zero.
    var t = sum + y          // Alas, sum is big, y small, so low-order digits of y are lost.
    c = (t - sum) - y // (t - sum) recovers the high-order part of y; subtracting y recovers -(low part of y)
    sum = t           // Algebraically, c should always be zero. Beware overly-aggressive optimizing compilers!
    // Next time around, the lost low part will be added to y in a fresh attempt.
 return sum
```

Comment: 4/3 * pi * r^3?

Comment: Are you asking for help with performance, or correctness?

Comment: @David I guess that the `vol2 = (4.0/3.0)*M_PI*(maxr*maxr*maxr);` in the code shows that the OP already knows the formula for the volume of a sphere and is in fact trying to do some numerical integration.

Comment: You know, in case the mathematical model of euclidean space changes in the middle of a computation.

Comment: Or you know, in case you want to numerically integrate the volume of a shape for which the formula isn't already known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as speed goes, I suspect (without having profiled it) that a lot of time is wasted converting between radians and degrees, and also computing all those `sin`s. AFAICT, `thetar` loops through the same values during each iteration of the outer loop, so it would likely be more efficient to pre-compute `sin(thetar)` once before the main loop, and do a simple lookup in your inner loop.

As for numerical stability, as `vol` gets larger and larger than `dv`, you will start losing more and more precision as you go along. You would in principle get better results if you could store all the `dv`s in an array, then sum it using a divide and conquer approach rather than a linear pass. Then again I count (only) `6 480 000` total iteration, so I think a `double` accumulator (holding 15-17 significant base-10 digits) can actually handle losing 6-7 digits without much trouble.

Comment: Many thanks, moving the thetad to thetar conversion and the sin(thetar) calculation out of the loop and into a lookup table has sped up my code by a factor of ~10!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your problem is: exiting the loop 1 iteration before you want it. You should not compare floating-point numbers for equality. A quick way to fix it is adding a small constant, e.g.

while (thetad<(180.0/adstep)**+1e-8**)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very thorough analysis but might give you some insight into the source of your error. In your code you are accumulating the value of 3240000 floating point numbers. As the value of `vol` increases, the ratio between `dv` and `vol` is increasing you are losing more and more precision in the addition.

A standard way to mitigate the loss of precision in accumulating many values to a single value (known as a *reduction sum*) is to perform the addition in blocks: for example, you could add together every 8 values and store them to an array, then add together every 8 values of that array, etc. until you are left with a single value. This is likely to get you a better result.

Also, it is worth considering that you are taking linear steps over a spherical surface, so you are not uniformly sampling your sphere. This is likely to affect your final result. One way of sampling the sphere uniformly is to take linear steps in the azimuthal angle `phi` from 0 to 360 degrees and take the `acos` of the range from -1 to 1 for your polar angle `theta`. See [this link on sphere point-picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I counted 3600 iterations of outer loop and 1800 of inner loop = 6.48M. How did you get only half that? Regardless, `double` has 15-17 significant figures, so losing 6-7 of them isn't too bad here IMHO.

Comment: @SchighSchagh That will be because I was looking at the number of iterations for the hemisphere (0-180 degrees in phi). Clearly it's not essential to do the reduction sum more carefully but if it's extra precision that the OP wants, it is still going to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *I think*, there are couple of errors in your function. I think both `phid` and `thetad` should be initialized to either `0` or `1.0`.

Second, you can gain quite a bit by reducing the number of floating point multiplications.

In the code below, I moved the contents of your `main` function to `volume1` and created a function `volume2` that contains slightly optimized code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void volume1(int numSteps)
{
   double thetar, phir, maxr, vol, dv, vol2, arstep, adstep, rad, rad3, thetad, phid, ntheta, nphi;
   cout << fixed << setprecision(17); // Set output precision to defined number of decimal places. Note Double has up to 15 decimal place accuracy

   vol=0.0;            // Initialise volume and set at zero
   adstep=360.0/numSteps;     // Steps to rotate angles in degrees
   arstep=(adstep/180.0)*M_PI;     // Angle steps in radians
   phid=1.0;            // Phi in degrees starting at adstep
   maxr = 1.0;         // Radius of the sphere

   // Loop to calculate volume

   while (phid<=(360.0/adstep))            // Loop over Phi divided by adstep. This scales the loop to the desired number of calculations.
   {
      phir=((phid*adstep)/180.0)*M_PI;        // Phi in radians
      thetad=1.0;                              // Theta in degrees, reset to initial adstep value
      while (thetad<=(180.0/adstep))          // Loop over Theta divided by adstep. Like Phi loop, this scales the loop to the desired number of calculations
      {
         thetar=((thetad*adstep)/180.0)*M_PI;    // Convert theta degrees to radians
         dv = ((maxr*maxr*maxr) * sin(thetar) * arstep * arstep) / 3.0;      // Volume of current segment
         vol += dv;      // Summing all the dv value together to generate a global volume
         thetad+=1.0;    // Increase theta (degrees) by a single step
      }
      phid+=1.0;      // Increase phi (degrees) by a single step
   }

   vol = vol*1.0; // Volume compensated for any reduction in phi and theta

   rad3 = (3.0*vol)/(4.0*M_PI);    // volume equivalent radius^3
   rad = pow(rad3,(1.0/3.0));      // volume equivalent radius
   vol2 = (4.0/3.0)*M_PI*(maxr*maxr*maxr);     // Calculated volume of a sphere given initial maxr

   // Diagnostic output
   cout << vol2 << " " << vol << " " << ((vol2-vol)/vol)*100.0 << endl << endl;
}

void volume2(int numSteps)
{
   double thetar, maxr, vol, vol2, arstep, adstep, rad, rad3, thetad, phid, ntheta, nphi;
   cout << fixed << setprecision(17); // Set output precision to defined number of decimal places. Note Double has up to 15 decimal place accuracy

   vol=0.0;            // Initialise volume and set at zero
   adstep = 360.0/numSteps;
   arstep=(adstep/180.0)*M_PI;     // Angle steps in radians
   maxr = 1.0;         // Radius of the sphere
   double maxRCube = maxr*maxr*maxr;
   double arStepSquare = arstep*arstep;
   double multiplier = maxRCube*arStepSquare/3.0;

   // Loop to calculate volume

   int step = 1;
   for ( ; step <= numSteps; ++step )
   {
      int numInnerSteps = numSteps/2;
      thetad = adstep;                              // Theta in degrees, reset to initial adstep value
      for ( int innerStep = 1; innerStep <= numInnerSteps; ++innerStep )
      {
         thetar = innerStep*arstep;
         vol += multiplier * sin(thetar);          // Volume of current segment
      }
   }

   vol = vol*1.0; // Volume compensated for any reduction in phi and theta

   rad3 = (3.0*vol)/(4.0*M_PI);    // volume equivalent radius^3
   rad = pow(rad3,(1.0/3.0));      // volume equivalent radius
   vol2 = (4.0/3.0)*M_PI*(maxr*maxr*maxr);     // Calculated volume of a sphere given initial maxr

   // Diagnostic output
   cout << vol2 << " " << vol << " " << ((vol2-vol)/vol)*100.0 << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
   int numSteps = 3600;
   clock_t start = clock();
   volume1(numSteps);
   clock_t end1 = clock();
   volume2(numSteps);
   clock_t end2 = clock();

   std::cout << "CPU time used: " << 1000.0 * (end1-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ms\n";
   std::cout << "CPU time used: " << 1000.0 * (end2-end1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ms\n";
}
```

The output I get, using g++ 4.7.3:

```
4.18879020478639053 4.18762558892993564 0.02781088785811153

4.18879020478639053 4.18878914146923176 0.00002538483372773

CPU time used: 639.00000000000000000 ms
CPU time used: 359.00000000000000000 ms
```

That gets you an improvement of about 44%.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are correct about my initialized phid and thetad. I've updated the original post to correct it.